# Redis command to get all available keys?

Tags: redis, redis-cli, redis-commands

Is there a Redis command for fetching all keys in the database? I have seen some python-redis libraries fetching them. But was wondering if it is possible from redis-client.

Comment: IMPORTANT CONTENT: _don't run `KEYS` on your production server unless you know what you're doing_.

Answer (score 960, accepted):

Try to look at [`KEYS`](http://redis.io/commands/keys) command. `KEYS *` will list all keys stored in redis.

**EDIT:** please note the warning at the top of `KEYS` documentation page:

> **Time complexity:** O(N) with N being the number of keys in the database, under the assumption that the key names in the database and the given pattern have limited length.

**UPDATE (V2.8 or greater):** [`SCAN`](https://redis.io/commands/scan) is a superior alternative to `KEYS`, in the sense that it does not block the server nor does it consume significant resources. Prefer using it.

Comment: CLI usage example: `redis-cli keys "*"`

Comment: Correction: All redis commands are single-thread and will block the server. The only difference is that `KEYS` has the potential of blocking the server for longer when querying a large data set

Comment: also don't forget to do "select DatabaseNubmer" first

Answer (score 206):

**Updated for Redis 2.8 and above**

As noted in the comments of previous answers to this question, `KEYS` is a potentially dangerous command since your Redis server will be unavailable to do other operations while it serves it. Another risk with `KEYS` is that it can consume (dependent on the size of your keyspace) a lot of RAM to prepare the response buffer, thus possibly exhausting your server's memory.

Version 2.8 of Redis had introduced the [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) family of commands that are much more polite and can be used for the same purpose.

The CLI also provides a nice way to work with it:

```
$ redis-cli --scan --pattern '*'
```

Comment: For me this command also worked `redis-cli --scan *` does it has some downside?

Answer (score 110):

It can happen that using redis-cli, you connect to your remote redis-server, and then the command:

```
KEYS *
```

is not showing anything, or better, it shows:
`(empty list or set)`

If you are absolutely sure that the Redis server you use is the one you have the data, then maybe your redis-cli is not connecting to the Redis correct database instance.

As it is mentioned in the Redis docs, new connections connect as default to the **db 0**.

In my case `KEYS` command was not retrieving results because my database was 1. In order to select the db you want, use [SELECT](http://redis.io/commands/SELECT).
The db is identified by an integer.

```
SELECT 1
KEYS *
```

I post this info because none of the previous answers was solving my issue.

Comment: how do I execute the command directly from a shell `redis-cli keys "*"`, rather than first connecting to the server.

Answer (score 64):

**Get All Keys In Redis**

Get all keys using the --scan option:

```
$ redis-cli --scan --pattern '*'
```

List all keys using the KEYS command:

```
$ redis-cli KEYS '*'
```

Answer (score 46):

-->Get all keys from redis-cli

```
-redis 127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
```

-->Get list of patterns

```
-redis 127.0.0.1:6379> keys d??
```

This will produce keys which start by 'd' with three characters.

```
-redis 127.0.0.1:6379> keys *t*
```

This wil get keys with matches 't' character in key

-->Count keys from command line by

```
-redis-cli keys * |wc -l
```

-->Or you can use `dbsize`

```
-redis-cli dbsize
```

Comment: Just copied the answers and tried. It gave "unknown command 'key'". "key" is not the command, "keys" is. Please correct `key *t*` to `keys *t*`.

Comment: Thanks dude for that information.it was my mistake.current i am on mobile.i will change that command eairlier.

Comment: Very useful cheatsheet this

Answer (score 24):

Take a look at following [Redis Cheat Sheet](http://lzone.de/cheat-sheet/Redis).
To get a subset of redis keys with the redis-cli i use the command

```
KEYS "prefix:*"
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can get all keys by using this

```
var redis = require('redis');
redisClient = redis.createClient(redis.port, redis.host);    
  redisClient.keys('*example*', function (err, keys) {
})
```

Comment: Not exactly what the OP was asking (redis-cli), but thanks for pointing this out nevertheless.

Answer (score 8):

SCAN doesn't require the client to load all the keys into memory like KEYS does. SCAN gives you an iterator you can use. I had a 1B records in my redis and I could never get enough memory to return all the keys at once.

Here is a python snippet to get all keys from the store matching a pattern and delete them:

```
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
for key in r.scan_iter("key_pattern*"):
    print key
```

Answer (score 6):

```
redis-cli -h <host> -p <port> keys *
```

where * is the pattern to list all keys

Comment: I had to quote the star, as follows: `redis-cli -h <host> -p <port> keys '*'`

Answer (score 5):

**KEYS pattern**

> Available since 1.0.0.
>
> Time complexity: O(N) with N being the number
> of keys in the database, under the assumption that the key names in
> the database and the given pattern have limited length.

Returns all keys matching pattern.

**Warning :** This command is not recommended to use because it may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases instead of KEYS you can use [SCAN](https://redis.io/commands/scan) or [SETS](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#sets).

Example of KEYS command to use :

```
redis> MSET firstname Jack lastname Stuntman age 35
"OK"
redis> KEYS *name*
1) "lastname"
2) "firstname"
redis> KEYS a??
1) "age"
redis> KEYS *
1) "lastname"
2) "age"
3) "firstname"
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get all the keys available in redis server, you should open redis-cli and type:
`KEYS *`
In order to get more help please visit this page:
[This Link](https://redis.io/commands#generic)

Answer (score 1):

If your redis is a cluster,you can use this script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
redis_list=("172.23.3.19:7001,172.23.3.19:7002,172.23.3.19:7003,172.23.3.19:7004,172.23.3.19:7005,172.23.3.19:7006")

arr=($(echo "$redis_list" | tr ',' '\n'))

for info in ${arr[@]}; do
  echo "start :${info}"
  redis_info=($(echo "$info" | tr ':' '\n'))
  ip=${redis_info[0]}
  port=${redis_info[1]}
  echo "ip="${ip}",port="${port}
  redis-cli -c -h $ip -p $port set laker$port '湖人总冠军'
  redis-cli -c -h $ip -p $port keys \*

done

echo "end"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply connect to your redis server using redis-cli, select your database and type KEYS *, please remember it will give you all the keys present in selected redis database.

Comment: beginner at redis here, can you detail your solution pls?

Comment: just fire redis-cli KEYS '*' command and you'll get the required keys.

Answer (score 1):

For the ones that wants a typescript helper (using ioredis)

```
import Redis from 'ioredis';
import { from, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { first, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export function scanKeysFromRedis(redisStore: Redis.Redis, key: string, 
target: number = 0, keys: string[] = []): Observable<string[]> {
  return from(redisStore.scan(target, 'MATCH', key)).pipe(
    first(),
    mergeMap((_keys) => {
      const _target = Number(_keys[0]);
      if (_target !== 0) {
        return scanKeysFromRedis(redisStore, key, _target, [...keys, ..._keys[1]]);
       }
      return of([...keys, ..._keys[1]]);
    }),
  );
}
```

and call it with: **scanKeysFromRedis(store, 'hello')**;

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel Framework then you can simply use this:

```
$allKeyList = Redis::KEYS("*");

print_r($allKeyList);
```

In Core PHP:

```
$redis = new Redis();

$redis->connect('hostname', 6379);

$allKeyList = $redis->keys('*');

print_r($allKeyList);
```

Answer (score -2):

We should be using --scan --pattern with redis 2.8 and later.

You can try using this wrapper on top of redis-cli.
https://github.com/VijayantSoni/redis-helper