# Show all keys in redis - in one line

Tags: database, linux, redis

I need to see all available keys in Redis. This question:

[Redis command to get all available keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252099/redis-command-to-get-all-available-keys)

Adequately covers the case where I run `redis-cli` with no arguments, then type `keys *`.

However, how do I get all keys with a single command?

`redis-cli keys *` returns:

> (error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'keys' command

Even though there are keys set, which checks out if you use the two-command solution.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to do

```
redis-cli keys '*'
```

to avoid your shell from expanding `*` into a list of filenames.

Comment: Such approach has a problem. KEYS block Redis (mention [here](http://redis.io/commands/scan)). So, it can significant decrease performance of Redis if it has a lot of keys. Instead of this command better to use [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) command or specialized tools like [Keylord](http://protonail.com/products/keylord) for manage Redis databases (it using SCAN command for load keys).