# How can I view all the stored session's REDIS keys and values in .Net application?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache, redisclient

```
Session["User"] = "LTA";
```

I used this session in my application.
I am unable to view this stored session values in .net application. 
I tried in below way:

```
ConnectionMultiplexer redisConnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("hostname,ssl=true,password=privatekey,allowAdmin=true");

var redisServer = redisConnection.GetServer("hostname", port);
```

Here I can able to get key list and client list by using below code:

```
redisServer.Keys()
redisServer.ClientList()
```

but key values are shows like

\skdkhciduhcahoaids_Data

\skdkhciduhcahoaids_Internal

Is this encrypted key values? (This is my first query)

Then,
This result doesn't change if I open the application in multiple browsers. But actually I want need 4 results if I open the application in 2 browsers because 2 session has been handled when the application run in 2 browsers.

Why it gives same result?

Can I able to view stored session values in redis connection? if yes means How can I view the session values?

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Inspiration: http://redis.io/commands/KEYS and this Python question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252099/redis-command-to-get-all-available-keys

Comment: @KristofferBohmann: Yes. We can get all keys through run the Redis-cli.exe. But I need that key list with value in .Net application.

Answer (score 0):

I Got a solution for first and second question:

**Is this encrypted key values?**

ASP.Net session id has been stored as a key of REDIS cache.

[REDIS's Key of Stored session value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycwpG.png)

**Why it gives same result?**

When I login with same user it's shows same result. But If I login with different user it's shows different result for every login.