# How to identify Redis keys from Redis-cli monitor command?

Tags: redis, redis-cli

Possibly related to - [Redis command to get all available keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252099/redis-command-to-get-all-available-keys)

I have a Redis server storing SixPack data (https://github.com/sixpack/sixpack - a framework to enable A/B testing). I can monitor the Redis server and see the following sample entries when I run monitor command:

```
$ redis-cli monitor|grep 'TEST'
```

I can see that there are several keys being used/set. I am attaching a sample below:

```
1581720438.878978 [15 127.0.0.1:39722] "GETBIT" "sixpack:e:-28591_:excluded" "2307"
1581720439.623866 [15 127.0.0.1:39722] "LRANGE" "sixpack:e:-28003_:alternatives" "0" "-1"
1581720439.624209 [15 127.0.0.1:39722] "HGET" "sixpack:e:-28003_" "traffic_fraction"
1581720439.624557 [15 127.0.0.1:39722] "GET" "sixpack:e:-28003_:winner"
1581720439.624822 [15 127.0.0.1:39722] "HEXISTS" "sixpack:e:-28003_" "archived"
1581720439.625110 [15 127.0.0.1:39722] "EVALSHA" "bcbf3b3ac336a33c2cd7ad0e1fca28db7b49fdee" "1" "sixpack:e:-28003_Recapture:users" "ac945bf7-285e-4f69-83fd-1336e084a318"
```

However, when I try to access the keys by running `$ redis-cli KEYS '*'` command, I only get an empty list `(empty list or set)`.

**Updated:** I checked that this is not a cluster setup. I also check the DBSIZE command. It returns 0.

How can I derive the keys from the MONITOR output? Is there a way to get all the keys in a Redis CLI?

Comment: Which Redis database number is the data in?  `redis-cli -n 1 GET "...." `

Comment: @AlisterBulman I checked that this is not a cluster. I ran $CLUSTER INFO, I got 'ERR This instance has cluster support disabled'. Doesn't that mean it is a single database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appropriate database index should be used when running the KEYS command if more than one Redis database is in use.

```
$redis-cli -n <DB number> KEYS '*' # or use --scan
```

Redis comes with 16 default 'databases' which can be used to split the keys up. To use them from the tool, `redis-cli -n 2` to start using the 3rd DB (the default is 0). Once inside the tool, or from the API, there is the `SELECT 2` command (again, to select the db to use).  More can be allowed for - it's just a number in the redis.conf file.

The Sixpack A/B testing tool configuration has two methods to be able to choose which Redis database to use - in the configuration is the key (eg)  `redis_db: 15`, or it, and more can be set by environment variable: `SIXPACK_CONFIG_REDIS_DB`, along with _PORT, _HOST, _PASSWORD & _PREFIX.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the hint from @AlisterBulman, I ran the INFO command like this.

```
 $ redis-cli INFO | grep keys
```

From the output I can see that the DB number '15' has the keys.

```
db15:keys=300869,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
```

Then I ran this command to get the keys.

```
$ redis-cli -n 15 KEYS '*'
```