# `redis-cli keys *` shows empty array, but `redis-cli keys my_key` shows the key

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I have a redis server running in a Docker container. I push values to a list in there from an outside script. When I'm in the redis container, however, `redis-cli keys *` returns `(empty array)`. This isn't an issue with selecting the correct database, I've tried that. See the following terminal output:

```
/redis_data $ redis-cli info keyspace
# Keyspace
db0:keys=1,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
/redis_data $ redis-cli keys *
(empty array)
/redis_data $ redis-cli select 0
OK
/redis_data $ redis-cli keys *
(empty array)
/redis_data $ redis-cli keys log_list # this is the key I've been pushing to
1) "log_list"
/redis_data $ redis-cli keys dne # a key I know doesn't exist
(empty array)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redis command to get all available keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252099/redis-command-to-get-all-available-keys)

Your issue may be that you need to escape `*` in your command, like `redis-cli keys \*`

Comment: @segFault that question does not directly address the issue I was having, but it is indirectly hinted at by some answers. You are right about escaping the wildcard expansion of `*`, which I discovered as I made this question. See my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that wrapping the pattern in quotes makes it function correctly. This leads me to believe the shell is expanding my `*` as a shell glob before redis can see it as a pattern. See the following terminal output:

```
/redis_data $ ls
dump.rdb
/redis_data $ redis-cli keys *
(empty array)
/redis_data $ redis-cli keys "*"
1) "log_list"
/redis_data $ echo *
dump.rdb
/redis_data $ echo "*"
*
/redis_data $ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "log_list"
127.0.0.1:6379> keys "*"
1) "log_list"
127.0.0.1:6379> exit
```

Observe my test with `echo` that confirms my theory. Functionally, my `redis-cli keys *` was getting executed as `redis-cli keys dump.rdb`, which of course gave an empty array. Interestingly, this error was only possible because I had exactly one file in my working directory. If I had more than one, I would've gotten `(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'keys' command` from `redis-cli keys *`, which might've tipped me off to the issue.

Also worth noting is that the issue can be avoided by running `redis-cli` and then doing redis commands from the `127.0.0.1:port>` prompt where no shell globbing is done, as seen above.